# How to use "IN" for more than one column

Tags: sql-server-2005

This question might be trivial or even silly but I was wondering if there is a way to use "IN" on more than one column on one to one matching.
For example I use

```
select emp_id from employee where emp_id IN (select emp_id from employee_other)
```

How could I achieve something like

```
select emp_id from employee where emp_id,emp_org IN (select emp_id,emp_org from employee_other)
```

I know I cant be using the following because it will simply do the union whereas I want a selection based on one to one record matching.

```
select emp_id from employee where emp_id IN (select emp_id from employee_other) and emp_org in (select emp_org from employee)
```

Please note that I am reluctant to use EXCEPT.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to use the EXISTS operator

```
select e.emp_id 
from employee e
where EXISTS
    (
    SELECT *
    FROM employee_other eo
    WHERE e.emp_id = eo.emp_id
        AND e.emp_org = eo.emp_org
    )
```

Comment: +1 Deleted my `JOIN` answer as this is closer semantically to `IN` (duplicates in the sub query won't cause duplicates overall)

Answer (score 3):

IN in Microsoft SQL Server only works with a single column, ie. you can only write `X IN (...)`, never anything remotely like `X,Y IN (...)`.

There are two ways to handle this, depending on your data:

- Joining with a sub-query
- Using EXISTS

To JOIN, do this:

```
select emp_id
from employee
    inner join (select emp_id,emp_org from employee) as x
    on employee.emp_id = x.emp_id and employee.emp_org = x.emp_org
```

Your example is a bit lousy, however, since you're using the same table.

To use EXISTS, do this:

```
select emp_id
from employee
where exists (
    select emp_id,emp_org from employee e2
    where e2.emp_id = employee.emp_id and e2.emp_org = employee.emp_org)
```

This, in the same way as the join, links the main table to the "sub-query" table, but whereas the join will produce duplicate rows if the "sub-query" produces multiple hits, the EXISTS clause will not.

Comment: very well explained. I actually  wanted a not NOT IN equivalent and hence joins were not a solution. join in my situation would not work (the stored proc in which i required this logic is quite complex), after i posed the question i realized it sounded way too simple and hence the join and subqueried answers. But exist solution worked pretty well.

Answer (score -1):

Use Inner Join

```
select e1.emp_id from employee  e1
inner join employee_other e2 on e1.emp_id = e1.emp_id and e1.emp_org = e2.emp_org
```

You may have to use Distinct in case the employee_other table causes dups.

```
select Distinct e1.emp_id from employee  e1
inner join employee_other e2 on e1.emp_id = e1.emp_id and e1.emp_org = e2.emp_org
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish with `emp_org in (select emp_org from employee)` isn't that always true?

does this work?

```
select emp_id from employee e
where exists (select 1 from employee_other eo  
              WHERE e.emp_id =eo.emp_id and 
              AND e.emp_org = eo.emp_org )
```

Comment: Sorry it was supposed to be employee_other in subquery. updated the question as well.

Answer (score -1):

You had it almost completely right in your second example.  You just need to add parens around your column names.

```
select emp_id 
from employee 
where (emp_id,emp_org) IN (select emp_id,emp_org from employee)
```

Comment: SQL Server doesn't support tuples in `in`

Comment: -1: Good for anyone using MySQL, useless for anyone using Microsoft SQL Server. Note that I only down-vote answers for questions where I myself provide an answer, where the answer I down-vote is outright wrong. In this case, it is.